# search/match a date on Google Sheets using Google script and copy a source range to a destination range OFFSET from that date

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm struggling with some simple copy/paste scripting in Google Sheets.  I'm a complete scripting newbie.  Advanced at Excel/Sheets.

I have a "Today" data entry sheet.  I have a "Program" sheet that stores data in a column under a Date header.  I want a macro/script that will:
1. cut data from a range on Today
2. search the date row in "Program" to Match whatever date is on the "Today" data entry page.
3. Finally paste data to a range on Program xx rows down from that identified date in step 2

Essentially I want to INDEX/MATCH in reverse.  Rather than return a cell in INDEX/MATCH, I want to copy to a cell.

Sheet is here:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19r6IbgdYCPOZjNr92MA0vAKQ_R2Fx5JohuC0DE8ekPo/edit?usp=sharing

Below is as far as I've gotten.  I can cut/paste from a specific cell to another cell.  But need to figure out "var destination" somehow.

```
function copydata2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getRange('Today!b11:g11');

  source.copyTo(ss.getRange('Program!d11:i11'), {contentsOnly: true});
  source.clear();
};
```

Comment: Hello, wanted to check if your issue had been solved

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function test2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var today = ss.getSheetByName("Today");
  var program = ss.getSheetByName("Program");
  var date = today.getRange("B4").getValue();
  var targetDates = program.getRange("D4:KL4").getValues();
  var column;

  // Get the target column.
  for (var i = 0; i < targetDates[0].length; i++){
    if (targetDates[0][i].toString() == date.toString()){
      column = i + 4; // To account for the first cols.
      Logger.log("found the date " + targetDates[0][i] + " at column " + column + " with i = " + i);
      break;
    }
    else continue;
  }

  // Move the values.
  today.getRange("B11:G11").moveTo(program.getRange(11, column)); // Sq w/ Belt
  today.getRange("J11:O11").moveTo(program.getRange(16, column)); // 2ct Paused Squat
  today.getRange("R11:W11").moveTo(program.getRange(21, column)); // Pin Squat
  today.getRange("Z11:AE11").moveTo(program.getRange(26, column)); // 3-0-3 Tempo Squat
  today.getRange("AH11:AM11").moveTo(program.getRange(31, column)); // Sq no Belt

  today.getRange("B19:H19").moveTo(program.getRange(37, column)); // 1 Ct Paused Bench Press
  today.getRange("J19:O19").moveTo(program.getRange(42, column)); // Overhead Press w/ Belt
  today.getRange("R19:W19").moveTo(program.getRange(47, column)); // Close Grip Bench Press
  today.getRange("Z19:AE19").moveTo(program.getRange(52, column)); // 2 Ct Paused Bench Press
  today.getRange("AH19:AM19").moveTo(program.getRange(57, column)); // 3 Ct Paused Bench Press
  today.getRange("AP19:AU19").moveTo(program.getRange(62, column)); // Pin Bench Press

  today.getRange("B27:H27").moveTo(program.getRange(68, column)); // Deadlift w/ Belt
  today.getRange("J27:O27").moveTo(program.getRange(73, column)); // Rack Pull - mid shin
  today.getRange("R27:W27").moveTo(program.getRange(78, column)); // 2 ct Paused Deadlift
  today.getRange("AH27:AM27").moveTo(program.getRange(83, column)); // Pendlay Rows
}
```

A couple things, I used `moveTo()` ([documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#movetotarget)), which cuts/pastes the values to the target, the only issue is that it overwrites the style format. When working with Sheets it's always better to use `getValues()` and `setValues()` to avoid making multiple calls to the API. In this case, however, since your data was organized in such a particular way it was better to work like this for complexity's sake. Please let me know if you have any doubts. I tested it on a copy of the sheet you provided and it worked as intended.